# Java app loads single url only after deployed

Tags: .htaccess

I have tested my Java app in local developed using jsp and servlets.

I have a domain and I copy the war in this domain. Now I am able to access this app as http://mdomain.com:8080/myApp without issues.

Now, I want to make this app available while hitting http://mdomain.com.
So, I configured the .htaccess file for this domain as follows,

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mdomain.com:8080/myApp/ [P]
```

Now, I am able to see the home page when hittng http://mdomain.com.

While I am hitting submit button, the page is loading only the home page and no respective pages displayed.

I am using apache tomcat7. Put my war in webapps.

What I am missing here?

May I copy the myApp folder to public_html folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mod_proxy` is enabled then you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mdomain.com:8080/myApp/$1 [P]
```

Note use of `$1` which is back-reference of captured value in `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thanks, How do we know that mod proxy is enabled? can you pls give some ideas on it and  "back-reference of captured value in RewriteRule"

Comment: Usually uncommenting `#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so` line in Apache's `httpd.conf` enables it. Bak-reference is for the value being captured in `(.*)` group. Start reading here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html